# Describe all possible intervals of the integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If an interval $I$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with the property that $a,b \in I$ and $a<c<b$, then $c \in I$.

Is it possible I union the integers? Where $I$ is a subset of the real numbers?

Comment: According to your definition, $\{x\}$ is an inerval, for any $x$. Then $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb Z}\{x\}$ writes the set of integers as the union of intervals

Answer (score 0):

One can verify that this property is equivalent to being a connected subset of $\Bbb R$, for instance the proof appears in Rudin. It's easy to verify that $I$ cannot be a union of integers then.